# Indicators do not appear at unity panel

Tags: 14.04, indicator

I noticed that applications indicators are no longer appear at the unity panel, only default ones (language, sound, battery...) are displayed.
When I try to load system load indicator from terminal, I get this message :

> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Application does
>   not handle command line arguments

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the `indicator-multiload` is already running. Kill the running process and it most likely runs.

The indicator wouldn't show up on my machine, giving me:

> (indicator-multiload:20479): Gdk-CRITICAL **:
>   gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion
>   'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed

I ended up using `gnome-system-monitor` applet. It's indicator is similar but I miss the summary `indicator-multiload` gave with just a click. This one simply opens the `system-monitor` when clicked.